# How to disable grid row line borders based on my value?

Tags: extjs6

I need to do kind of grouping in Extjs Grid. whenever first field's value changes only i need to display row border. otherwise I need to remove the border.

I have tried adding Css for making bottom-border: 0 and invoking the `Css` from `gridrowclass`. but it is not working.

`.odd.x-grid-row .x-grid-td 
    border-bottom: none !important;`

and consume above `Css` from `Getrowclass`. but this is working only in Ext 4.2 version. it is not working in 6.0

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to completely disable row lines:

```
rowLines: false
```

Create a css class the put the lines back on the row:

```
.row-with-border {
    border-bottom: 1pt solid gray;        
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

And add logic to the grid whether or not to render the row with border:

```
viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
            if (record("myField)=="Myvalue")
               return "row-with-border";
            else
               return "borderless-row";
        }
    },
```